# Update multiple rows with just one query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following data:

```
id = 1
name = 'john'

id = 2
name = 'jimmy'
```

etc.

Is there a way to update my table using just one query?

```
Table
id | name
1  | johnny
2  | james
```

Comment: Check this blog: http://www.kavoir.com/2009/05/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-one-single-query.html - The first result when i searched for Update multiple rows with single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin Smith's solution is certainly the best solution for a small number of rows. If a greater number of rows is to be updated you'd better off issue several `UPDATES` with different values, possibly with the help of prepared statements.

Just for the fun, I devised another solution:

- create a temporary `MEMORY` table
- insert your values into this table (can be done in one shot if you build your insert query properly)
- update your main table with a query like this : `UPDATE your_table JOIN temp_table ON (<insert JOIN condition here>) SET your_table.field1 = temp_table.field1, your_table.field2 = temp_table.field2`.

Well this smells. Seriously. Use a prepared `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET    name = CASE
                WHEN id = 1 THEN 'johnny'
                ELSE 'james'
              END
WHERE  id IN ( 1, 2 )
```

Or another possibility ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04d527/1))

```
UPDATE YourTable a
JOIN
   ( SELECT 1 AS id, 'johnny' AS name
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 AS id, 'james' AS name
   ) b ON 
   b.id = a.id
SET a.name = b.name;
```

Comment: This is not really extendable. I'm going to be doing about 100 rows

Comment: So ask questions that reflect your actual needs then! What is the source of these 100 rows. Another table?

Comment: @MartinSmith I can't help but face-palm; +1 none the less.